# Weather Icons of different Sizes in OpenWeatherMap

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icons, openweathermap

I am using OpenWeatherMap to get the weather data for my app.With the response data openweather is sending a weather icon code and they have a specific icon for that code which is very small ,but i want a bigger icon to use in my home page.Is there any alternative to get a bigger Icon from OpenWeatherMap.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions) page to get all the icons (in @1x, @2x and @3x). Download them and add them to your assets and the system will automatically get the right one for you.

The you could increase them in your UIImageView if you want since they are `png`, I don´t think you will decrease the quality.

```
// Parameters x, y, width, height
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

Comment: Ya,I am getting the 1x image from this there only , by making a call to http://openweathermap.org/img/w/%@.png . How to get the 2x and 3x icons

Comment: I miss read the page, it does not seem to provide any retina icons. Try the imageView solution that I suggested.

Comment: I have already tried that ,the image is getting blurred.Any other alternative?

Comment: Then I think your only solution is to download your own images and use them (I would recommend that, because you can choose your own icons). This is an example of icons http://www.pixeden.com/icon-fonts/weather-7-icon-font-set that has a set for Retina

Answer (score 2):

This icon set is a lot clearer. Just change the folder from w to wn and add @2x before the .png:

`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01d@2x.png`

[image]

Comment: your link is broken, could you fix this please?

Comment: Sorry. It's not a direct link, It's code. The variable for the icon you want goes inside the braces. You could never hard-code a link for every weather icon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to enlarge the png icon like this:

```
const weatherIcon = document.querySelector(".weather-icon"); 
const iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/";
weatherIcon.src = iconURL + response.weather[0].icon + "@2x.png";
```

You should be able to replace the `@2x.png` with also @3x.png. To me the easiest way is to break it down to separate variables and then combine them. This code is inside my `displayData` function. I would put this inside your function that displays your data.

P.S. coding newbie here still learning!!!

Answer (score -2):

I use these icons in my UWP app: 
http://www.zephyros.wetter.com/apps_und_mehr/website/api/downloads/